# Hashing in SHA512 using a salt? - Python

Tags: python, salt, sha, hashlib, saltedhash

I have been looking through ths hashlib documentation but haven't found anything talking about using **salt** when **hashing** data.

Help would be great.

Comment: A salt would be separate from SHA512.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Samir's answer is correct but somewhat cryptic. Basically, the salt is just a randomly derived bit of data that you prefix or postfix your data with to dramatically increase the complexity of a dictionary attack on your hashed value. So given a salt `s` and data `d` you'd just do the following to generate a salted hash of the data:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.sha512( s + d ).hexdigest()
```

See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) for more details

Answer (score 19):

Just add the salt to your sensitive data:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.sha512()
>>> m.update('salt')
>>> m.update('sensitive data')
>>> m.hexdigest()
'70197a4d3a5cd29b62d4239007b1c5c3c0009d42d190308fd855fc459b107f40a03bd427cb6d87de18911f21ae9fdfc24dadb0163741559719669c7668d7d587'
>>> n = hashlib.sha512()
>>> n.update('%ssensitive data' % 'salt')
>>> n.hexdigest()
'70197a4d3a5cd29b62d4239007b1c5c3c0009d42d190308fd855fc459b107f40a03bd427cb6d87de18911f21ae9fdfc24dadb0163741559719669c7668d7d587'
>>> hashlib.sha512('salt' + 'sensitive data').hexdigest()
'70197a4d3a5cd29b62d4239007b1c5c3c0009d42d190308fd855fc459b107f40a03bd427cb6d87de18911f21ae9fdfc24dadb0163741559719669c7668d7d587'
```

Answer (score 12):

Salting isn't a magical process that the library needs to help you with—it's just additional data provided to help in defending against rainbow table attacks.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.sha512()
>>> m.update(b"Nobody inspects")
>>> m.update(b" the spammish repetition")
>>> m.digest()
b'\xd0\xf4\xc1LH\xadH7\x90^\xa7R\x0c\xc4\xafp\x0fd3\xce\t\x85\xe6\xbb\x87\xb6\xb4a|\xb9D\xab\xf8\x14\xbdS\x96M\xdb\xf5[A\xe5\x81+:\xfe\x90\x89\x0c\nM\xb7\\\xb0Cg\xe19\xfdb\xea\xb2\xe1'
>>> m.update(b"My super-secret salt.")
>>> m.digest()
b'\xcd\xd7K\xd9!~\xa8\x1d6\x9b\xa6\xde\x06\t\x02\xa1+}\xaeNA\x94a`\xaa\xf4\xe9\xb5\xff\x1f\x9cE\x84m\xbb\x98U\xb4z\x92\x9e\xe8\xc9\xc2\xc8\x8f\x068e\xb0\r\xed\xb7\xde\x80\xa6,\n\x111w{\xa2\x9b'
```

Comment: Last sentence is most accurate ever to understand why we need salt

Comment: That sentence is incorrect, it doesn't stop rainbow tables from working, it makes it SIGNIFICANTLY harder for them to work.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a replacement for crypt(), newer versions of glibc have SHA-512-based "$6$" with a variable iteration count (see [Ulrich Drepper's page](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/sha-crypt.html), which has a description and links to a complete C implementation of `sha512_crypt_r()`).

Writing your own crypto is highly unadvisable — the above `sha512(salt+password)` doesn't help against a brute-force attack.

For generating salt, use something like `os.urandom(16)` for random bytes or `''.join(map(lambda x:'./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[ord(x)%64], os.urandom(16)))` for random base64-alike chars (for use with crypt()-alikes).

(I say base64-alike it's not the same as the Base64 in PEM/MIME.)

Answer (score 3):

use passlib, writing your own password crypto is an almost sure way to failure.

Answer (score 2):

SHA512 isn't a great way to store hashed passwords these days.  You should be using bcrypt or something similar.  What's important is that salting is built in and that the algorithm has a significant work factor.

If you salt your SHA512 passwords by simply appending (or prepending) the salt to the plaintext, anyone who gets their hands on a set of your hashed passwords and applies a modern cracking tool (http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/05/how-crackers-make-minced-meat-out-of-your-passwords/) will be able to see the concatenated password+salt values and will probably, through trivial pattern matching, be able to separate the password portion from the salt portion for most if not all of the accounts in question.

I haven't thought this through all the way, and I am by no means a security expert, but it seems to me that if you were to encrypt (using, for example, AES256) the password using the salt as the key, and then hash *that* with SHA512, you'd be safe from the vulnerability I described above.

However, at that point you've put in more effort than it would have taken to switch to bcrypt and you still wouldn't have the protection of a work factor, so I would only recommend an approach like that if the environment you're working in does not offer that option.

Comment: That article is about a password list that used only MD5 and wasn't salted. Do you have a source for the assertion that, "anyone who gets their hands on a set of your hashed passwords and applies a modern cracking tool will be able to see the concatenated password+salt values?" Preventing them from doing that (e.g. via rainbow tables) is exactly the point of using a salt in the first place, is it not?